# Tagging: Should we add file format tags?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Since we've been discussing some typography tags:

- How do we feel about image format tags such as [eps](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/eps), [jpg](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/jpg) or [png](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/png)?
- And what about file formats like [ai](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ai) or [psd](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psd)?

As an example, I just tagged [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/27746/how-to-delete-the-border-in-this-ps-graphic) with EPS.

Comment: resounding 'yes'!

Comment: I thought we already had most of them. Definitely yes! Also, just an idea - we could add links in our tag descriptions to other SEs that have the same tags with a snippet about their scope around it. Extra helpful for everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Generally, I think it would be good with more tag diversity. Format tags would be good, *provided it is relevant to the question* in the sense that discussing some **effect** in Photoshop does not require a .psd tag. It will of course have a photoshop-tag.

It would have to have some relevance to the question, not generally Photoshop = .psd.

On tag diversity in general, I think i would be good with a Meta post with some brainstorming.

I see tags as a fairly hierarchical structure, where you go from the most general to as specific as possible in five tags. Example; someone has trouble with layers and saving:

1. bitmap
2. photoshop
3. layer
4. save /file-type
5. .psd

So, I am all for it.